# Why are key codes seen differently on Windows and Linux?

Tags: python, linux, keyboard

I am writing a program in Python using a library called Pynput. This library can listen for keys by utilizing key codes such as [these ones](https://asawicki.info/nosense/doc/devices/keyboard/key_codes.html). In Windows, this has been working fine and the key codes are the same as in the above link, but in Linux, some keys are off by 32, while others are off by 16.

For example, the ! key appears as 049 when I run my program in Windows, but as 033 when I run it in Linux (difference of 16). The r key in Windows appears as 82, while it appears as 114 in Linux. Lastly, the numpad keys 0 - 9 show as key codes 096 - 105 in Windows, but in Linux their key codes show as "None" except for numpad 5 which shows as 65437. This last example is especially strange to me.

The result of this is that my program works fine in Windows, and typing in !reload is interpreted as it is typed, but in Linux, it is interpreted as !r5lo14 instead. The most confusing part about this is that only some keys are interpreted correctly while some are not. The letters are all off by 32, but r, l, and o are correct, e, a, and d are not correct. The ! key is also correct despite being off by 16 instead of 32. The numpad keys all interpret correctly except numpad 5.

This is how I got the key value from my program:

```
# Starts Pynput listener. When you press a key, it calls word_builder with the argument key
with Listener(on_press=self_word_builder) as self._listener:
    self._listener.join()

# Builds a word as you type
def word_builder(self, key):

    self._key = key

    # Assigns self._keycode with the string value of key
    self._keycode_to_keydata()

    # MAP VK KEYS HERE. Below codeblock shows this in more detail

    # Output resulting key
    print(self._keycode)
```

I just wanted to note that this isn't a problem with Pynput as it was not recognizing the numpad keys even on Windows. We fixed this by remapping keys pynput read as vk, such as vk_numpad1. This is when it no longer worked correctly on Linux. This remap is as per below:

```
    # Map virtual key codes for key codes outside the typical ASCII keyboard range
    self._vk_map = {
        110: '.',  # [Num .]
    }
    # Numpad support
    self._vk_map.update({i: f'{i - 96}' for i in range(96, 106)})  # [Num 0] = 96, [Num 1] = 97

    if hasattr(self._key, 'vk'):
        # Map the vk values
        if self._key.vk in self._vk_map:
            key = self._vk_map[self._key.vk]
```

Before our fix, everything worked correctly on Windows and Linux except for the numpad keys, so it is almost as if Linux shows some keys as virtual keys and not others, but I'm not sure how to confirm this.

In my attempts to fix this, I have tried searching for a Linux equivalent of the Window key codes I posted above, but I couldn't find anything. The closest thing I found was an app on my machine called Character Map which found these keys in separate lists. For example, when I searched for my lower case e it came up wrong (101) but upper case E was right (069). Each of these appeared in a different list of characters that was named differently. The ! appeared in a third list of characters. Does Linux have any default list of key codes, or is it different on each Linux machine?

I also looked into fixing this programmatically, but I can't find any other people listing this issue anywhere I have looked. I don't really understand what is happening so it is very difficult for me to even attempt a fix. I have only found the cause (character codes are appearing incorrectly in Linux) but as they do not diverge from the Windows equivalent with the same amount, I can't just fix this offset. I was hoping with this post to get an understanding of what is happening, and any suggestions for how best to tackle this issue. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Why aren't you using Pynput's key code conversion functionality?

Comment: @thatotherguy I'm not familiar with this and couldn't find it in the documentation. Do you have a link? This sounds like it could fix this problem for me.

Comment: The documentation is [here](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html). There's an example on top and API reference on the bottom